# How to get the value associated to a char in c?

Tags: c

I would like to know how could I use the value of an input char in C.

Ex:

The user types **a**, how could I use the value of a (97) in my code? Is that possible?

MORE DETAILS:
I made a while loop to get inputs from the user. If the user inputs a number 1-9, then I increment a variable called numbers, but the problem comes now: If the user types a for example, I made a condition to check wether the input is greater than 95 or not, and it does not work. What I want is to get this input (scanf("%d")) and if it is a letter (ascii >= 97), then increment another variable called letters.

**Part of the code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    long long int teclas=0, letras=0, numeros=0, i=0, aux=0, k=0, j=0, flag=0,
    numprint=0, seq=0;
    scanf("%lld", &teclas);

    while(i<=teclas){
        scanf("%lld", &aux);
        if(aux>0 && aux<10){
            numeros++;
            aux = 0;
        }else if(aux>96 && aux<123){
            letras++;
            aux = 0;
        }
        i++;
    }
```

Comment: It already is that value.

Comment: What are you going to use it for? Anyway... the answer is yes. If you do `'b' - 'a'` the result is 1. If you do `100 - 'a'` the result is 3. .... Internally a char is just a number

Comment: @4386427 I made a loop while to get inputs from the user. If the user inputs a number 1-9, then I increment a variable called numbers, but the problem comes now: If the user types **a** for example, I made a condition to check if this input is greater than 95, and it does not work. What I want is to get this input (scanf("%d")) and if it is a letter (ascii >= 97), then increment another variable called letters.

Comment: @Gamechanger You should post your code instead of describing it in words.

Comment: @4386427 then we found an error:( I posted part of the code, hope it helps you to understand what I am trying to do.

Comment: @Gamechanger Did you see my answer? Your code can not parse input like the letter `'a'`.

Comment: @4386427 yes I did, and thank you so much for that:D I'm just trying to find out what I am going to do because I can't use strings, and if I can't do what I am doing teorically I'd have to make a variable for every input.

Comment: @Gamechanger My answer shows you what to do... I'll make a little update in 2 min

Comment: @4386427 well, I think it actually solves my problem to be honest:D I'll try to implement that, thank you so much:D:D:D:D

Comment: @4386427 sorry for not getting it at the first time I read, now I see it does solve the problem:D

Comment: @Gamechanger Answer updated

Comment: @4386427 I can't even thank you enough for that:D thanks for solving my problem and being kind to explain:) that helped me a lot

Comment: regarding: `(scanf("%d"))`  if the user enters 'a'  this call to `scanf()` will fail.  I.E. the return value from `scanf()` will be 0.  Also, note the syntax is not correct.  the call to `scanf()` needs a second parameter, the address of where the input value is to be stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I want is to get this input (scanf("%d")) and if it is a letter (ascii >= 97), then increment another variable called letters.

The short answer is: You can't read a letter using the format specifier `%d`

But you can do it in another way by checking the return value of `scanf`.

Something like:

```
int input_number;
char input_char;
if (scanf("%d", &input_number) == 1)  // Try to pass input as an int
{
    // The user typed a valid integer number which is now stored in input_number
    if(input_number>0 && input_number<10)
    {
        numeros++;
    }
}
else if (scanf("%c", &input_char) == 1)  // Didn't get an int so read a single char
{
    // The user typed a non-integer char which is now stored in input_char
    //
    // Now you can do:
    if (input_char >= 'a' && input_char <= 'z')
    {
        letras++;
    }
}
else
{
    // Input error
    exit(1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use the ASCII value of characters. Refer to the below example.

```
char c;
scanf("%c", &c);

int asciiValue;
asciiValue = c; // Here we are typecasting char to int implicitly. 
printf("ASCII val of %c is %d", c, asciiValue);
```

Here the variable `asciiValue` will have the int value of the character, and you can use it for any operations that you may want to perform in your code.

Note:
char is 1 byte signed integer whereas int is a 4-byte signed integer.

Comment: There is no need for `asciiValue = c;` because if you pass an integer type smaller than `int ` to a variadic function it is automatically promoted to `int` (and `float` is promoted to `double`).

Answer (score 0):

```
char c='a'
int value=a;
printf("%d",value);
```

This is called as `implicit casting`.output of this program will be `97` which is `ascii code` for `a`;

OR You can directly print it using

```
printf("%d",'a');
```

Output

```
97
```

Comment: You can print it directly with `printf("%d", c);` because if you pass an integer type smaller than `int ` to a variadic function it is automatically promoted to `int` (and `float` is promoted to `double`).

Answer (score 0):

If you want the ASCII code then you can just do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char a = 'a';
    int x = (int)a;
    printf("%d", x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't need the cast.

Answer (score 0):

You already get what you need: the value in the variable.
Wheter it is a character('A','a') or an integrate number(65, 97) only depends on how you interpret it. See the example below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  char input_buf = 0;

  printf("input any character:\n");
  while (1) {
    scanf("%c", &input_buf);
    if (isprint(input_buf)) {
      printf("\nthe value you just input: %c, the value: %d "
             ",\n Ctrl+C or Ctrl+Z to exit\n",
             input_buf, (int)input_buf);
      printf("\ninput any character:\n");
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```